# Inductor as current source

Tags: inductor, constant-current

In this schematic for an induction heater, there are two inductors used for current sources. My question is what happens if I increase/decrease the inductance? For example, what would happen if I replaced the two 100uH coils with 1mH coils?
[image: https://markobakula.wordpress.com/power-electronics/500w-royer-induction-heater/]
Source: https://markobakula.wordpress.com/power-electronics/500w-royer-induction-heater/

Comment: *there are two inductors used for constant current sources.* I disagree with that, inductors cannot be used as a constant current source. These inductors are used to **bias** the transistors and maybe also form a resonating tank together with the induction coil and the Cap bank. They could also just be used as "chokes" though. The "6.1 A" means that these inductors need to be able to work with currents up to 6.1 A, meaning the inductor's **saturation current** needs to be more than 6.1 A.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie . . it is common in the induction heating industry to refer to an H bridge with inductors in series with the output of inverter as a "current source".  The word "constant" is Not used. The inductors provide current after the active devices are turned off. The series inductors do not substantially affect the resonant frequency of the tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inductors limit the maximum output current of the inverter. Replacing the inductors as you suggest will reduce the maximum current to 1/10 of the original maximum current (at resonance).

It is common in the induction heating industry to refer to an H bridge with inductors in series with the output of inverter as a "current source". The word "constant" is Not used. The inductors provide current after the active devices are turned off. The series inductors do not substantially affect the resonant frequency of the tank.